# using setattr() to set None or blank value

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Is there a way to use `setattr()` method to set a `None` or blank value?

I tried both:

`setattr(instance, 'attr_name', None)` which causes `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

and

`setattr(instance, 'attr_name', '')` which causes `ValueError: Cannot assign "''": "MyModel.attr_name" must be a "MyAttrModel" instance.`

I can not do that the way `instance.attr_name = ''` because the `'attr_name'` is just an element of the table of strings, like: `none_attributes = ['attr_name', 'attr2_name', 'attr3_name']`.
All the attributes from the table are `ForeignKey` type.

The current code looks like that:

```
for attr in none_attributes:
    setattr(instance, attr, None)
```

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: @Charnel all the attributes from the table are `ForeignKey`. All of them has also `null=True` and `blank=True` .

Comment: The problem is not the `setattr`, it is the `or attr in none_attributes`, `none_attributes` is `None`, so ou can not enumerate over it.

Comment: @Dibidalidomba, for `ForeignKey` to set a value use `attr3_name_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a value to the `ForeignKey` you need an object.

> ValueError: Cannot assign "''": "MyModel.attr_name" must be a
> "MyAttrModel" instance.

You can use instead an attribute with `_id` at the end.

```
none_attributes = ['attr_name_id', 'attr2_name_id', 'attr3_name_id']

for attr in none_attributes:
    setattr(instance, attr, "")
```

Behind the scenes, Django appends **"_id"** to the field name to create its database column name, see [**Django ForeignKey**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

Also as  **@Willem**  pointed out, you should to check that `none_attributes` are iterable.

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

if isinstance(none_attributes, Iterable):
    for attr in none_attributes:
        setattr(instance, attr, None)
```